# PHP: How can I read from a folder filenames and load this file names in a Java script array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have in a sub folder some image files. I would like to get the file names before and after a copy operation to know the new file names.

This new file names (not the files, only the names and extension) need to be saved in a data field of my MySQL Database.

In this data field are always all file names of the pictures saved, that belong to the current record.

I was thinking about four ways:

1) Read the file names via jQuery, if this is possible. Then save the data via Ajax to the MySQL.

2) Read the file names via PHP and the result should be sent to a Javascript array that I can save the data in a MySQL  field. It is nearly the same as option 1).

3) If possible, read the file names in PHP and save them direct in PHP in the field of a table.

4) Read in the multifileuploader function the file names in a additional javascript array, that I can start another ajax action to fill the MySQl Data field with it.

I still  dont understand why PHP lose immediately data if I add before the main operation another code. It is strange.

Because then would it be easier. Just do in the upload.php after success, the MySQL  action  to save the upload file names (they are anyway in this PHP array) to the MySQL database.

I use for the file operation a public code from somebody else.

Here is the code how I save this files:

File body_editarticles.php

```
    <?php session_start();

        $_db_host = "myserver.com:3306";
        $_db_username = "admin0";
        $_db_passwort = "star1dgffh";
        $_db_datenbank = "sob";
        $_db_currentID ="";

        $_link = mysql_connect($_db_host, $_db_username, $_db_passwort);

        if (!$_link)
        {
            die("No Connection to the database: " .
                mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($_db_datenbank, $_link);

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body class="page page-id-11505 page-template-default" onload="jsRecordCurrent();">

    <div id="page-wrap">

    <?php
    include('includes/header.html');
    ?>

    <div id="hiddenID" style="display: none;"></div>


    <div id="mulitplefileuploader" title="">
        <br>
        Upload
    </div>
    <div id="status"></div>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            var settings = {
                url: "upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif",
                fileName: "myfile",
                multiple: true,
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                {
                    $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload successful</font>");
                },
                onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                {
                    $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload failed</font>");
                }
            }
            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

        });

        </script>

    </div>

    </div>

    </div>

        <div id="aside">

        </div>

        <br class="clearfloat" />
    </div> <!-- End of main container -->

    </div><!-- END Page Wrap -->

    <div id="footer">
        <br class="clearfloat" />

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

file "upload.php"

```
    <?php

    //If directory doesnot exists create it.
    $output_dir = "sobimages/";

    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        $ret = array();

        $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
        {

            if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
            {
                $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
                //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

                $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
            }
            else
            {
                $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
                for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
                {
                    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                    $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName );
                }

            }
        }
        echo json_encode($ret);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick suggestion to your topic

php

```
$files = scandir('/files');
die(json_encode($files));
```

jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'link to php file',
    method : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
           console.log(data);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the beforehand filenames you can use `$_FILES['myfile']['name']`, this will give you the original filename as it would appear in the folder of the client system, as for after the move, unless you change the names they will be the same, but you could also iterate over the directory and spit out the data.

```
<?php
// Define the filepath
$strOutputDirectory = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'sobimages';
// Define a filename placeholder
$arrFiles = [];
// Iterate over the directory
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($strOutputDirectory) as $dirEntity) {
    // Check for a file
    if ($dirEntity->isFile()) {
        array_push($arrFiles, $dirEntity->getFilename());
    }
}
// Return the JSON
echo json_encode($arrFiles);
```

​

```
jQuery.getJSON('/path/to/file.php', function(arrFile) {
    // Log the output
    console.log(arrFiles);
});
```

For more information on directory iteration, see:  [PHP:  DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)